# React useEffect issue... variable inside async function is getting a delayed updated value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Here is my code: I am trying to connect to supabase and i am getting a console 400 error twice but then it connects. It is due to userId variable, if i put the userId string i do not get the error. userId is being updated in a function just above this useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
async function example() {
try {

          const { data, error } = await supabase
          
            .from('profiles')
            .select()
            .eq('id', userId );
    
      };
     
      example();
    }, [userId]);
```

I added this at the bottom and it never connected.

`if(userId) return: example()`

Any ideas what i can do to avoid any console errors. I cant use conditions on hooks to avoid running useEffect with an empty string. Do i need to setup useProviders to set the variable outside of the component, that way the userId variable is set before the component is ran?

Comment: I think, you have to post the complete code of this file. Atleast the userId flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must check the `userId` value availability at the beginning of your hook; try adding the following:

```js
useEffect(async () => {
    if (!userId) return;
    const { data, error } = await supabase
            .from('profiles')
            .select()
            .eq('id', userId );
}, [userId]);
```

Comment: This is it. I appreciate your help. Not sure why before works but it does. Thanks